# How to download file after making api call to server in react/saga?

Tags: reactjs, react-redux, redux-saga

I'm trying to make an api call to server and download file with successful response.

```
function downloadFilesComponent() {
   const {payload} = useSelector(state => state.reduxstore)

   const handleDownload = () => 
  {
   dispatch(action.downloadfile({id:fileId, filename: fileName})
  }

  return ({
     <button onClick={handleDownload}/>
     })
}
```

Once action reaches saga, i make a request with payload to API and  have the response coming back from API as a octate stream,how can i handle this response to download .txt file? Please help. Thank you in advance.

Comment: Can you provide bit more information? What do you want to do with the downloaded file? Are you asking about mainly about how to structure your components/sagas to star the download or about how to do the download itself?

Comment: @MartinKadlec I edited the post, I would like to hear both if you are willing to share the information. Preferably i would like to know about download itself of octave stream.